# Sequelize update not accepting `null` as an attribute for typescript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I am getting a weird error with the following db request:

```
RequestApp.update({
    is_selected: false
  }, {
    transaction: dbTransaction,
    where: {
      is_selected: null,
      request_id: request.id,
      user_id: {
        [db.Sequelize.Op.ne]: id
      }
    }
  })
```

The error I get is the following:

Error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Object | WhereOptions[]'.

Technically I can get rid of the error by setting `null as any`, but it seems like there should be a way to set it directly to the where clause.

Is there a way to do this without explicitly overriding the data value?

Comment: What about `is_selected: {},`? It looks like the same behavior than `null` but `{}` will fit to `Object` type

Comment: Is selected is a boolean type. The weird thing is that I am pretty sure this corresponds to https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/sequelize/index.d.ts#L3191 which has null as a valid type.

Comment: I think type definition of `where` is here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/sequelize/index.d.ts#L278 and `AnyWhereOptions` looks like this: `{
        [field: string]: WhereOptions<any>[] | Object;
    }`

Comment: I had the same issue and it turns out that type of column in typescript must be null | boolean. Then it doesn't give any error.

Answer (score 4):

The attribute of your model definition must be "type | null" and you need to inform Sequelize manually that your field is type number and the right operator to check if is null is Op.is.

Example:

Model definition:

```js
class MyModel {
  @Column(DataType.NUMBER)
  score: number | null;
}
```

Query:

```js
MyModel.findAll({ where: { score: { [Op.is]: null } } });
```

Comment: so, the option for `null` type is not automatically added when we define `allowNull: true`?

Answer (score 0):

Could use:

```
is_selected: { [Op.eq]: null }
```